# Character encoding issue - black diamond question marks on imported post excerpts

Tags: database, encoding, characters

I am having some issues with character encoding on imported posts from an old Wordpress install. I am getting black diamonds with question marks on some of the posts I have imported to a new install. The issue only seems to exist in post excerpts, when I click to view the full post, the missing characters are not there and when I click "edit post" they are not visible in the backend either. I have found several topics regarding this issue, but none of the solutions have worked for me so far.

The new install is using `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');` in `wp-config.php` whereas the old site(where I imported the posts from) is using `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');`

I'm not sure what character is even having trouble being encoded. I think it's just an `nbsp;` but there are other places with `nbsp;` that are not showing as question marks, so I'm stumped. Any quick remedy for this issue?

**Things I have tried**:

- Commenting out `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');` and `define('DB_COLLATE', '');` (This created even more question marks)
- Adding `<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">` to `header.php`
- Setting back to `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');` in the `wp-config.php`

Comment: Have you tried setting the define back to UTF-8, along with the database?

Comment: I tried setting the define back to `UTF-8`, but the problem persisted. I'm not sure how to safely make the change to the database, since the database seems to be using a mix of encodings(for example, I have tables from a plugin using `utf8_general_ci`, whereas the default Wordpress tables are using `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`).

Comment: Take a backup of your database then look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94789/how-to-convert-a-mysql-database-from-utf8mb4-to-utf8

Comment: Have you checked the database is actually using that encoding? `define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'emoji' );` won't change your tables retroactively. Or that the version of MySQL you're using actually supports `utf8mb4`